# WEKA "no classifier built"

Tags: weka

I need to use WEKA to for running an experiment for a baseline that uses J48() decision tree. Since the original code is very long, I am sharing a piece of code in the following that essentially captures the same issue.

```
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier;

public class MyTest{
    protected AbstractClassifier classifier;

    public MyTest(){
        this.classifier = new J48();
    }

    public void getLocalClassifier(){
        System.out.println(classifier); 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyTest mt = new MyTest();
        mt.getLocalClassifier();    
    }
}
```

I even had a look to the WEKA source code for J48() and found that only when the `m_root == null`, it prints 'No classifier built'.

```
if (m_root == null) {
    return "No classifier built";
}
```

Comment: You should train the classifier first. Check the `buildClassifier` method.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!